# Data (phone numbers) deleted in batch using profile not deleted from contacted records

Tags: contacts

Wanted to reclassify 'Other Mobile' type phone numbers as 'Home Mobile' type phone numbers. Exported, copied data from 'other mobile'column to "Home Mobile column' in CSV file, leaving "other mobile column empty', and then reimported. Numbers were now in 'home mobile' field but also remained in "other mobile' (ie now appeared twice in each contact record. Created profile including phone number fields. Did batch edit using that profile. Deleted numbers in the innappropriate fields. Updated contact (saved). All appeared to work BUT the numbers are still showing in the "other mobile field. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure you have done anything 'wrong'. I think the phone and some other fields are designed so an empty field does not overwrite existing data - i remember this being an issue people have hit when trying to do what you tried via the Import route. Sounds like the same is happening via the Profile.

Probably doesn't seem like a 'great' solution, but if you have mysql access, could you use your Batch update Profile to change all the numbers you want to eg 'xyz', and then use mysql to find and delete that data?

Comment: Great. Could you pls accept and +1 the answer as that is how this system helps others find answers.